# Passing a function to select html in React

Tags: reactjs

I mapping over data which displays different select option dropdowns. I need my onChange function to be on the select tag to capture the selected option, but the select tag is before the function is initialized so I'm not sure how to go about passing the function into it.

```
                <select onChange={onChange}>  <--- onChange function cant be passed  here
                    {options.map((attribute) => {
                        function onChange(event) {
                            const newSelected = { ...selected };
                           newSelected[attribute.title] = event.target.value
                        }

                        return (
                            <option value={attribute.index}>{attribute.value}</option>
                        )
                    })}
                </select>
```

Comment: Is this in JSX? Is it React? Something else?

Comment: This answer might seem trite or dismissive, but I don't mean it to be: I think the answer is, Don't do it that way. You shouldn't be defining `onChange` in the `.map` function

Comment: It conceptually doesn't make sense. `<select onChange={onChange}>` implies a singular `onChange` function, but you're defining a new `onChange` function in every iteration of `.map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `onChange` so that it uses the information on the event object it receives to find the right entry in the list, something like this:

```
<select onChange={event => {
    const attribute = options[event.currentTarget.value];
    const newSelected = {
        ...selected,
        [attribute.title]: event.currentTarget.value,
    };
    // ...
}}>
    {options.map((attribute, index) => {
        return (
            <option key={attribute.value} value={index}>{attribute.value}</option>
        )
    })}
</select>
```

It's hard to be sure the details of that are right without knowing the structure of `options` or what you want `newSelected` to be, but I think I've mostly inferred it from the question's code. Note that I changed `attribute.index` to `index` in the `map` call, and that I added a `key` (you need `key` on any array you render), assuming that `attribute.value` is unique.

That said, if `attribute.value` is unique, I think I'd use it instead of `index` or `attribute.index`:

```
<select onChange={event => {
    const attribute = options.find(({value}) => value == event.currentTarget.value);
    const newSelected = {
        ...selected,
        [attribute.title]: attribute.index,
    };
    // ...
}}>
    {options.map(({value}) => {
        return (
            <option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>
        )
    })}
</select>
```

Comment: You beat me to it, and with code at that!

Comment: I commented a critique about the `index` field but you already fixed it. Fully agreed on that count now!

Comment: This is what I was trying to achieve, thanks I poorly worded the question.

Comment: @walker1 - Can't have been that bad, I and others understood it! :-) Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I think I sort of see why you're doing it the way you're doing it, so let me try to address how to handle it differently:

First of all, you're doing it because the `onChange` function needs access to the `attribute.title` value. So for you, you're thinking the easiest way to get that value is to define the function in the `.map` function, where you have access to each individual attribute as it's coming through.

You can't, though. As I said in my comment: It conceptually doesn't make sense. `<select onChange={onChange}>` implies a singular `onChange` function, but you're defining a new `onChange` function in every iteration of `.map`.

So what you need to do is define `onChange` before your `render` function, and then inside that you have to *find the matching `attribute`* inside the `options` array, so that you can then use `attribute.title` as you like.

[edit] TJ Crowder gives a specific code example of how to do that.

Comment: That was my thought process yes. Thanks that completely makes sense I have found this very useful